# Spring Security overriding configuration has no effect

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, configuration, oauth-2.0

I want to learn some Spring Security. I'm having troubles configuring my webpage properly. I try to override the auto-configuration with an own `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` and own `@Bean ClientRegistrationRepository`

But when i call `localhost:8080/` i always get redirected to the /login although i permitted the pages "/", "home", "index" to everyone

Even when i remove the `.oauth2Login()` the security config there is always an oauth2LoginFilter instantiated

my configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    public class OAuthLoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/index").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and();
             //.oauth2Login();    
    }
}

@Bean
public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository() {
    return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(this.googleClientRegistration());
}

private ClientRegistration googleClientRegistration() {
    return ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId("google")
        .clientId("client-id")
        .clientSecret("client-secret")
        .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC)
        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
        .redirectUri("{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}")
        .scope("openid", "profile", "email", "address", "phone")
        .authorizationUri("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth")
        .tokenUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")
        .userInfoUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo")
        .userNameAttributeName(IdTokenClaimNames.SUB)
        .jwkSetUri("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/certs")
        .clientName("Google")
        .build();
}
```

spring boot log

```
2017-11-29 16:41:23.057  INFO 15004 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1, [
org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@10acd6,
org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@49c8f6e8, 
org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@338cc75f,
org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@3cff0139,
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@6e1b9411,

org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@3d8b319e,
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter@5017e1,

org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@117bcfdc,
org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@4e73b552,
org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3bdb2c78,
org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@61dde151,
org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@7c9bdee9,
org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@53a5e217,
org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@25e49cb2]
```

org.springframework.security: DEBUG

```
2017-11-30 15:08:58.563 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 1 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'
2017-11-30 15:08:58.564 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 2 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 3 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@346defc9
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 4 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter'
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}'
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 7 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter'
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/'; against '/login/oauth2/code/*'
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 8 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 9 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 10 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 11 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9d900631: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 12 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.session.SessionManagementFilter  : Requested session ID 1F3038DE1C8283AC4C24CF2D7952A166 is invalid.
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 13 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : / at position 14 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /; Attributes: [authenticated]
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9d900631: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2017-11-30 15:08:58.565 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@76bff3b8, returned: -1
2017-11-30 15:08:58.580 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:204) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.doFilterInternal(OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.java:109) [spring-security-oauth2-client-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.invokeWithWrappedRequest(DebugFilter.java:90) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.security.web.debug.DebugFilter.doFilter(DebugFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.0.0.RC1.jar:5.0.0.RC1]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_151]

2017-11-30 15:08:58.580 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.util.matcher.AndRequestMatcher   : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/**', GET]
2017-11-30 15:08:58.580 DEBUG 10060 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request '/' matched by universal pattern '/**'
...
```

Does Spring boot override my configuration?

Comment: Are you really want to use a release candidate instead of stable version? Spring Security 5 is not released yet.

Comment: Well I'm new at Spring Security and started my research with quick guides on the web and the examples of the [Spring Security Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#samples). The samples there are written with the new Spring Security 5 version. Especially the SpringSecurityOAuth2Client seems not to be implemented in the previous version

Comment: do you think this could be a bug in the early version?

Comment: I don't know, but most answers and tutorials are for Spring Security 4. You will find not much support for Spring Securiy 5 until it is released. BTW: As vsoni wrote, the `@Configuration` should moved to your `OAuthLoginSecurityConfig` class (in Spring Security 4 this should work).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding @Configuration on your OAuthLoginSecurityConfig class, and make this inner class static if required, like ...

```
@Configuration
public static class OAuthLoginSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home", "/index").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and();
             //.oauth2Login();    
    }
}
```

Comment: When i do i get an error, because 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService' is no created (@ConditionalOnMissingBean)

Comment: Bean method 'authorizedClientService' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter; SearchStrategy: all) found beans of type'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter'securityConfig.OAuthLoginSecurityConfig